# Comparing attributes of two shapefiles in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, shapefile

I have two identical shapefiles of Estonia. The only difference is that the attribute table of shapefile 1 has mean temperatures from the period of 1991-2000 and the attribute table of shapefile 2 has mean temperatures from the period of 2001-2010.

I want to compare these two shapefiles now and the result should be a shapefile which shows the difference in mean temperature between the two periods.

How can I do it?

I tried Feature Compare but it did not work. I got an error.

Comment: What does the error message say?

Comment: @artwork21 There is no special error message, but when I use the Feature compare I cant see the columns to compare? I cant see the 1991-2000 column and the 2001-2010 column. Maybe because the name is not the same?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that there is a unique key in common to both shapefiles I think you should be able to use the [Join Field](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000065000000) tool to join the fields you want from `shapefile2` onto `shapefile1`.

Then you can do whatever calculations/comparisons that you wish.

Comment: Isn't there something easier? I thought that it is possible to input two datasets and get a third dataset (with the differences in temperater) as result?

Comment: I cannot think of anything easier than this - have you tried it and encountered a problem?  Alternative approaches would be to convert your shapefiles to rasters so that you can do map algebra on them, or write an ArcPy script to use cursors, but I think this way is the easiest.

Comment: I tried it. But why does it take so long? When I do a table join I have to wait about 5 seconds but the field join (only 1 field) is working for 15 minutes now